# Connection from AWS ElasticBeanstalk node.js to AWS ElastiCache Redis times-out

Tags: node.js, redis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elasticache

I have my AWS ElasticBeanstalk node.js environment running and AWS ElastiCache Redis with AUTH enabled.

When my application tries to talk to Redis, it gets stucked and the ALB replied with connection time out.

## Tried so far

- I double-checked the security groups and tested that I can connect using `redis-cli` from my AWS Elastsic Beanstalk's EC2 instance to Redis and that works.
- Double-checked the connection string which my application uses. They are ok.

Any ideas where to look for? What could block my application which is on that EC2 to talk to Redis?

## Solution

The connections string which works on local machine, does not work on AWS ElastiCache. I had to add `tls` and `password` in the connection string.

Comment: What does the log from redis tell you?

Comment: Where can I find Redis log?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that to connect to ElastiCache Redis, I had to add two more properties to the connection string than when connecting to Redis on my local machine.

This is how the connections strings turned out

```
{
      host: `${process.env.REDIS_HOST}` || "localhost",
      port: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
      password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD,
      tls: {}
}
```

Previously, I did not pass `password` and `tls` in here.

Comment: Hola did you actually enable password ? If so how did you enable password authentication in your elastic cache cluster. Can you please suggest? I'm having difficult time connecting to redis using bull js